# What's the easiest (and ideally safest) way to get from Dubai to Abu Dhabi?

Tags: dubai, uae, abu-dhabi

I shall be visiting and staying with some friends in Dubai, and want to take a day trip out to visit another group of friends in Abu Dhabi. Without hiring/driving a car, what's the easiest way to get from one to the other and back for under 100 USD? [According to Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Abu_Dhabi#Dubai_International_Airport), a taxi from Dubai seems to only be about 300AED (~80 USD) - are taxis really that cheap in the UAE?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest way is indeed a taxi, and yes, that price sounds about right, although it's a regular metered fare so the exact cost will vary.  Not every taxi will be willing to up and off to Abu Dhabi on a lark though, but the airport taxi stand can sort one out if you ask, or you can call and book a cab.  As for safe, well...  most UAE cabbies drive fairly sanely by the standards of the region, but the Dubai-Abu Dhabi highway always has the occasional blinged-up rich kid doing 300km/h in the fast lane in Daddy's Lamborghini.

The cheaper and safer, but slower and less convenient, option is the [Emirates Express](http://www.dubai-bus.com/buses-stops-map/dubai-inter-emirates-buses) bus, Dhs 20 one-way.  Buses leave from Ghubaiba station, on the Dubai Metro Green Line, every 30 min or so.

Comment: Could you have answered the question without _"the occasional blinged-up rich kid doing 300km/h in the fast lane in Daddy's Lamborghini"_? Such things don't add much value to the answer and say more about you than anyone else.

Comment: The OP asked for a "safe" option, but the UAE's highways are not safe, and people driving *way* above the speed limit are a major reason why. http://www.thenational.ae/uae/transport/police-lower-speed-limit-at-abu-dhabi-dubai-motorway-black-spot

Comment: I think what the intent was to have reliable transport (that is safe) rather than some shady cabs which are common and a ripoff. There is no highway that's safe, as idiots are not restricted by nationality. I also don't see how your bus option is "safer" since they all have to travel on the same road.

Comment: The UAE's highways are objectively more dangerous that most developed countries.  And if you were going to be hit by a speeding Ferrari, would you prefer to be in a bus or a taxi?

Comment: Objectively based on what? Fast cars? In the many lists out there of the world's most dangerous roads Egypt is the only middle eastern country listed. They list dangerous roads based on the number of accidents and the condition of the roads themselves.

Comment: Objectively based on road deaths. UAE ranks badly compared to eg. the UK, and particularly badly compared to other countries of similar wealth - it's the second largest cause of death! http://m.livescience.com/43466-countries-with-deadliest-roads.html

Comment: But at the end of the day, all I'm saying is I did not feel safe sitting in the back seat of a taxi at night on my way to Abu Dhabi, with lunatics careening past at 300km every few min, and the stats back up my impression. No, it's not the most dangerous thing I've done, but given a good alternative I wouldn't do it again.

Comment: I drove the Sheikh Zayed road both ways last year, and it did not seem to me to be any more dangerous driving than the highways around Toronto (though perhaps that says more about Toronto than the UAE). There's some (electronically imposed tolls) that I guess the taxi driver would collect.

Answer (score 8):

Taxis are that cheap in Dubai, and in general the public transport system is one of the best in the middle east.

Your options for Dubai - Abu Dhabi:

1. Public Transport (routes, timetables, etc. available at [this website](http://wojahti.rta.ae)). The first bus to Abu Dhabi leaves at 5 AM and the journey takes about 90 minutes given the traffic conditions.
2. [Careem](https://www.careem.com/dubai) - this comes to $110 but it is the most comfortable and safe way to go. I would recommend this over all other options.
3. Flydubai has a [bus service](http://www.flydubai.com/en/about-us/bus-service/) that you can book as well. Its 40 AED one way; from the airport to the airport.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add up, a bus from Dubai to Abu Dhabi would cost much less. There are two buses E100 and E101 that take you from Al Ghubaiba Bus Station (Dubai), or Ibn Battuta Metro Station (Dubai), right to Abu Dhabi Bus Station.

If you're settling in Dubai check DubaiHow, they actually have the routes of each bus in Dubai in details without the hassle of maps and some out-dated Wikiroutes: https://dubaihow.com/dubai-bus-routes/